# Unable to start apacheがでてapacheがスタートできない。

Tags: php

Bitnamiからdokuwikiをインストールし、apacheも順調に動いていたのですが、dokuwiki manager toolで起動してもUnable to start apacheがでて起動できなくなりました。
どうしたらよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

自己レスです。
windowsの「サービス」にてApacheをスタートアップの種類を「自動」から「自動(遅延開始)」で今のところ動いているようです。